# Merging arrays in form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, submit

i have an simple form, like:

```
<tr data-good-id="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="good_id[item1]" value="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="size[item1]" value="XL"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="color[item1]" value="White"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="count[item1]" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr data-good-id="2">
    <td><input type="text" name="good_id[item2]" value="2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="size[item2]" value="L"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="color[item2]" value="Black"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="count[item2]" value="10"/></td>
</tr>
```

And i need perform this function for each line of table after submit:

```
foo_func($good_id, $size, $color, $count);
```

sample:

```
foo_func('1', 'XL', 'White', '1');
foo_func('2', 'L', 'Black', '10');
```

How to make it? I did not think beyond.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its best that an item contains its properties, rather than properties containing items. Do it like this:

```
<tr data-good-id="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="item[1][good_id]" value="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[1][size]" value="XL"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[1][color]" value="White"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[1][count]" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr data-good-id="2">
    <td><input type="text" name="item[2][good_id]" value="2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[2][size]" value="L"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[2][color]" value="Black"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[2][count]" value="10"/></td>
</tr>
```

and then with  run your function for each item

```
foreach ($item as $c_item) {
    foo_func($c_item['good_id'],$c_item['size'],$c_item['color'],$c_item['count']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is safe... try this:

```
foreach ($_POST[good_id] as $index => $good_id) {
    foo_func($good_id, $_POST['size'][$index], $_POST['color'][$index], $_POST['count'][$index]);
}
```

Comment: you are missing a $ on your first index ;)